# if statement with not equals in Java android

Tags: java, android, string, if-statement, equals

I need to take the three strings and make sure that they are the same and that they are not null or empty.

This code is working fine in a Java online compiler but not in Android Studio.

```
 int i = 0; ...

    B1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B1);
    B2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B2);
    B3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B3);

    B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            if (i==0){
                B1.setText("X");
                i++;}
            else if (i==1){
                B1.setText("O");
                i = 0;}
        }
    });

  // the same for B2 and B3...

    String SB1 = B1.getText().toString();
    String SB2 = B2.getText().toString();
    String SB3 = B3.getText().toString();
    if (SB1.equals(SB2) && SB2.equals(SB3) && !SB1.equals("") ){
        Win.setText("win");
    }
```

Comment: "the condition is false i think!" is exactly the moment were you start the debugger, debug through your code and see exactly where something is not the way it is supposed to be.

Comment: Take care of Java naming convention. variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: B1 , B2 , B3 are buttons. All 3 buttons have same text? are you sure?

Comment: show full code of your activity

Comment: I don't put anything in the buttons text, so it equals to "" ?

Comment: the full code is just the same as this, for the others buttons

Comment: the code for the X O Game, And i now only want to see when the three first  buttons text are same or not if it's all X or O then show "you win".  Also sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure that two strings are same or not...

---

```
String one = "RAMESH";
String two = "RAMESH";

if((one.contentEquals(two))
{
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Strings are same", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Strings are NOT SAME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

---

You can check in your case like :

---

```
if(SB1.contentEquals(SB2) && SB2.contentEquals(SB3))
{
     if(!SB1.equals(""))
     {
          Win.setText("win");
     }
}
```

---

Hope it helps

Comment: If you find it useful then kindly upvote and accept it as answer, So it will be helpful to find others who are searching for this

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition as

```
String SB1 = B1.getText().toString().trim();
String SB2 = B2.getText().toString().trim();
String SB3 = B3.getText().toString().trim();

if(SB1.equals(SB2) && SB2.equals(SB3) && !SB1.isEmpty()){
     Win.setText("win");
}
```

But your condition getting false because, all buttons having empty text / no text and it get false due to **SB1.isEmpty()** and when you performs click on B1 button, it changes the text on it, which does not match condition for equality of string. So make sure to change text of B2 and B3 buttons too.